# Why is this simple O(n) Haskell algorithm behaving more like O(2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, caching, big-o, time-complexity

Haskell caches results of pure function calls, one of the many reasons for the separation between pure and impure behavior. Yet this function, which should run in O(n) where n is `50` below, runs really slowly:

```
lucas 1 = 1
lucas 2 = 3
lucas n = lucas (n-1) + lucas (n-2)
map (lucas) [1..50]
```

The first thirty terms or so together compute in under a second, then 31 takes half a second or so, 32 takes a full second, 33 takes a few seconds, 34 takes 6 seconds, 35 takes 11 seconds, 36 takes 17 seconds...

Why is this function so slow? If the GHC interactive runtime is caching results, then each call to `lucas` should only involve summing of the two previous cached terms. One addition operation to find term 3, one additional addition to find term 4, one additional addition to find term 5, so term 50 is reached with only 48 additions total considering caching. The function shouldn't take anywhere near a second to find at least the first few thousand terms, why is the performance so terrible?

I've been waiting for more than half an hour now for `lucas 500` to compute.

Comment: there is no caching - at least not in the way you expect - this will behave the same as in any other language

Comment: The behavior is not *O(n^2)*, but *O(2^n)*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hahahaha, I see I was a bit too optimistic

Comment: anyway both versions I mentioned should get you the first 500 numbers in a few seconds (basically the time it takes to print them on screen)  ;)

Comment: As an aside, you say "Haskell caches results of pure function calls" with confidence. Why? Is there a source out there somewhere that we can correct? So very many people seem to have this misconception somehow...

Comment: I believe it may have been written in Learn You a Haskell

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Where?

Comment: You probably misinterpreted what *sharing* is about. If you have `let x = some_function a b c in [x,x,x]` then the `x` value is computed only once. Lazyness means that `x` is computed only when something tries to "look at" one of the elements of that list. Once this is done the value is computed and all 3 elements will reference it.  A lazy language without sharing would compute the value only when the element is inspected, but accessing two elements would cause two function calls to compute the values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your version is very slow is that there is no *memoization* of the `lucas (n-1)` and `lucas (n-2)` parts - so both values will be recalculated (recursively) over and over again - which is painfully slow.

The solution is to keep the calculated values somewhere:

### using list-lazyness

Here is a simple version that will do the same as your code-snippet but should be way faster - it will keep the already calculated parts in the list itself:

```
lucasNumbers :: [Integer]
lucasNumbers = 1:3:zipWith (+) lucasNumbers (tail lucasNumbers)

first50 :: [Integer]
first50 = take 50 lucasNumbers
```

the reason why this is faster is that now the lazyness of the list will help you memoize the different parts

You can learn much about this if you look for [Fibonacci sequences in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence) (it's really just the same as yours ;) )

### using `unfoldr`

another (maybe less *magic* seeming) way to do this is using [`Data.List.unfoldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) - here the already calculated parts (or those that matter - the last and second-to-last elements) will be in the *state* you pass around for the **unfold** operation:

```
lucasNumbers :: [Integer]
lucasNumbers = unfoldr (\ (n,n') -> Just (n, (n',n+n'))) (1,3)
```

---

to your comment/question:

assuming you are talking about `x(n) = x(n-1)^2-2` then you can do it like this:

```
lucasLehmer :: [Integer]
lucasLehmer = 4 : map (\ x -> x^2-2) lucasLehmer
```

which will yield something like this:

```
λ> take 5 lucasLehmer
[4,14,194,37634,1416317954]
```

maybe you should try the `unfoldr` version yourself

Comment: How would you do this with list operations that only apply to the previous term, like the Lucas-Lehmer numbers, where the first is 4 and each subsequent term is equal to two less than the previous term squared?

Comment: It's even easier in that case. You can do it with `unfoldr`, but `iterate` is written for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @amalloy yes of course (for the `lucasLehmer` sequence) that's true ... this and maybe hundred other ways to do it ;) - I did not want to add yet another way (which will not work for the original question - or not easily - anyway)